# How to display the selected variable in a select list from POST form

Tags: php, html

My select list is part of a POST form. 
If I have understood it correct; when the user select one of the variables from my array cats it stores the option as $value.
I then want to show this $value on another page, how can I do this?

```
<select name="cats">
    <option value="">choose a categori</option>
    <?php
        foreach($cats as $key => $value):
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
        endforeach;
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you mean: *How can I loop through array and use the key/values as options?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selected item from the `<select name="cats">` is stored in `$_POST['cats']`. Just as every other post variable too.